# Dragging fabricjs object from threejs object

Tags: javascript, three.js, fabricjs

i'm trying to create something like this https://www.owayo.com/konfigurator_html/index.php?sport=football&product=shirts_f3&lang=en&land=us#

Right now i can select and deselect fabricjs object from 3d model directly. The code is look like this

```
function onMouseClick(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var array = getMousePosition(raycastContainer, evt.clientX, evt.clientY);
  onClickPosition.fromArray(array);
  var intersects = getIntersects(onClickPosition, object.children);
  console.log(intersects);
  if (intersects.length > 0 && intersects[0].uv) {
    var uv = intersects[0].uv;
    console.log(uv.x * 512);
    console.log(uv.y * 512);
    intersects[0].object.material.map.transformUv(uv);
    var selected = getObjectUnderPoint(uv);
    if (selected != null) {
        console.log(selected);
      controls.enabled = false;
      canvas.setActiveObject(selected);
      canvas.renderAll();
    } else {
        canvas.discardActiveObject().renderAll();
      controls.enabled = true;
    }
  } else {
    controls.enabled = true;
  }
}

function getRealPosition(axis, value) {
  let CORRECTION_VALUE = axis === "x" ? 4.5 : 5.5;
  return Math.round(value * 512) - CORRECTION_VALUE;
}

var getMousePosition = function (dom, x, y) {
  var rect = dom.getBoundingClientRect();
  return [(x - rect.left) / rect.width, (y - rect.top) / rect.height];
};

var getIntersects = function (point, objects) {
  mouse.set(point.x * 2 - 0.97, -(point.y * 2) + 0.97);
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  return raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);
};
var getObjectUnderPoint = function (uv) {
  var cp = { x: uv.x * 512, y: uv.y * 512 };
  var objects = canvas.getObjects();
  for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    var obj = objects[i];
    if (!canvas.containsPoint(null, obj, cp)) continue;
    var isIntersecting = canvas.isTargetTransparent(obj, cp.x, cp.y);
    if (isIntersecting) {
      return obj;
    }
  }
  return null;
};
```

here's my development so far https://custom.speedjersey.com/3d-Tshirt-design-master-edit/

Now what i wanted to do is dragging them around and even scaling them, does anyone know a way to do that?

Comment: Your development so far looks really good. But what is it you're tying to fix/improve? What is needing to be dragged around/scaled exactly? I see that dragging/scaling/panning the 3D model around works well on the link provided, so I just want to make sure I understand.

Comment: on my current development, i wanted to make the text draggable directly from the 3d object